# How do I style every last element of every line/row differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to create a grid using

```
display:inline=block
```

I need to style every last element of every line/row differently. I tried

```
nth-child
nth-of-type
```

However, when I use that, it gets mixed up with my other grids. So how do I do it without adding new classes?

Comment: We'd need to see your specific HTML/CSS, ideally, in a JFiddle, to comment. `:last-child` would probably help buy it may not work in your circustances

Comment: @Paulie_D http://michellecantin.ca/test/features/grids/ This is my document

Comment: No...not a link...the HTML & CSS preferably in a reduced case JSFiddle. We shouldn't need to dig through your code with Developer Tools to find a specific rule.

Comment: @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=kfTw3ULKmE

Comment: I don't think there is any selector that will help you as you do not have any wrapping element defining what a 'row' is and where it starts and stops. See answer by @sissy.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i've seen from your code, you cannot use nth-child to achieve your goal. I will try to explain with an example: 
you want the 4th and the 8th child of the section class="four" to be coloured red. In order to use nth-child or nth-of-type, you have to reference to children starting from their parent, i.e. body. So it's difficult to say what number in the list of body's children are the 4th and the 8th children of section class="four", and it's not flexible at all.
I think you are using it in the wrong way, something like section.four:last-child, which is not correct. Please check: [w3schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Furthermore, nth-child and nth-of-type cannot be used with a selector but only with an element, so no way to do something like .four:nth-child (in the case you make a div with class="four" outside your sections).

So the only way, without adding more classes is jquery, like this:

```
$('.four').last().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: While I agree, and have upvoted, it's perhaps worth using alternate references (W3Schools doesn't have a good reputation, here), such as [`:nth-child()` at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), or [`:nth-child()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: It only changes the last one. I'm looking to change every last element of every row.

Comment: yes this is just an example: you have to repeat it for all your needed cases. For example in rows with two element per row you will do something like this (in case you have 6 elements):
    `$('.two').nth-child(2).css('background-color', 'red');
    $('.two').nth-child(4).css('background-color', 'red');
    $('.two').last().css('background-color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, if you associate every nth-child with a class of some type and every nth-of-type with another class use can style each one differently.
For instance,

```
<html>
<div class="nth-child"> 
   //some code
</div>

<div class="nth-of-type">
 //some code
</div>

</html>
```

Then in you CSS file you would do something similar to this:

```
.nth-child
{
  //style rules
}
.nth-of-type
{
//style rules
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for, without a posted example it is kinda hard to understand what you exactly mean. But if you want to us JS for this then you would create a JS function 
obtain all elements in your page using `"var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("nth-child")"`
the you would loop through "elements.length" setting each element style to "none"

Comment: "In CSS3" you would use the `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-classes respectively... which is what is meant in the question.

Comment: @user2917241 I don't really understand what you are trying to say. You are using nth-of-type and nth-child as classes. I don't want to add any more classes.

Comment: OK now I think I understand you Michelle. Just do what Sissy suggested if you really do not want to add anymore classes.However, the method i described initially works only if you assign the elements you want with a specific user defined class. Nonetheless it will work if you choose to add more classes. Otherwise Jquery is your answer